# Error in a simple hello world android program

Tags: android

I just created a simple hello world program, all codes are fine it seems, but something makes the android to show "unfortunately app needs to close" error

the startingPoint.java code which is the launcher class

```
package demo4;

import com.example.demo4.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class startingPoint extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    }
```

the main.xml which is the layout for launcher class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the androidmanifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demo4"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
          <activity
            android:name=".startingPoint"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the logcat

```
    08-30 12:46:22.921: D/AndroidRuntime(326): Shutting down VM
    08-30 12:46:22.941: W/dalvikvm(326): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity       ComponentInfo{com.example.demo4/com.example.demo4.startingPoint}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.demo4.startingPoint in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.demo4-2.apk]
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.demo4.startingPoint in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.demo4-2.apk]
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
    08-30 12:46:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Try  cleaning project...Have you added this class in manifest.xml?

Comment: Post AndroidManifest.xml, it looks like you've specified the activity incorrectly in there

Comment: It seems that android try to find the class in your package `com.example.demo4.startingPoint`, but in your code the package is just demo4. Try to change this line by `com.example.demo4`.

Comment: Your package name is wrong, you probably renamed the packages but the IDE did not. You'd have to clear all IDE related project data (.idea folder and .iml file in the project folder), then reimport it to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I post my comment as an answer :)

It seems that android try to find the class in your package `com.example.demo4.startingPoint`, but in your code the package is just `demo4`. Try to change the first line by `package com.example.demo4.`

Answer (score 0):

Resloved...it was as indicated by Mtoypc. the package name was different and it was not reflected in the startingPoint.java